# Define horizontal initial scrolling point

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, overflow

I have an element that contains a fixed width table, and when the screen size became smaller, the table can be scrolled horizontally.
My question is, is there a way to define the initial scrolling point, lets say, 50px from the left?

```css
body {margin: 0}

.wrapper {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

table {
  width: 800px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

th, td {text-align: center; border: 1px solid}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">Heading</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 1</td>
      <td>Data 2</td>
      <td>Data 3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('wrapper_id').scrollLeft = 50px;
```

or jQuery:

```
$("#wrapper").scrollLeft(50)
```

Comment: Yeah exactly. :)

Answer (score 4):

Another way you can use

```
                              $(".wrapper").css("scrollLeft","50")
```